# toJSON() becomes part of public interface but not toString()

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract base class which I'd like to have generic implementations of `toJSON()` and `toString()`. For `toString()` I can implement like so:

```
public toString() {
  const obj: IDictionary = {};
  this.META.properties.map(p => {
    obj[p.property] = (this as any)[p.property];
  });
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

Then, assuming a **Person** object which extends my abstract base class like so:

```
export class Person extends BaseSchema {
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @length(20) public name: string;
  @property public age?: number;
  @property public gender?: "male" | "female" | "other";
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @pushKey public tags?: IDictionary<string>;

  // prettier-ignore
  @ownedBy(Person) @inverse("children") public motherId?: fk;
  // prettier-ignore
  @ownedBy(Person) @inverse("children") public fatherId?: fk;
  @hasMany(Person) public children?: fk[];

  @ownedBy(Company) public employerId?: fk;
}
```

> Note: the decorator code is non-exciting and I'm excluding it as I think it'll unnecessarily complicate things ... if people are super interested all decorators can be found at [here](https://github.com/forest-fire/firemodel/tree/master/src/decorators)

I then have an input signature somewhere that looks like:

```
 public set<T>(path: string, person: T) { ... }
```

It's entirely fine to pass in the public methods and it does NOT require that I pass in a `toString` method. However, when I do *exactly* the same thing with a method called `toJSON()` then it gives me the error:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'.
>     Property 'toJSON' is missing in type '{ name: string; age: number; }'

[image]

Does anyone understand why this is the case?

Comment: Can you please provide the definition of `Person`?

Comment: @behrooz I have added, hope that helps

Comment: But you are not passing in an instance of person, you are passing in an object literal that has the fields but not the method of `Person`

Comment: It does not complain for `toString` because every object including any object literal has a `toString` method

Comment: Oh, why doesn't the object literal also have toJSON?

Comment: Or maybe a better question, is there a compact way of removing fields from an interface that is defined by a class? In this case i'd like to remove `toJSON` as the signature in my "set" method

Comment: Does your `BaseSchema` class have the `toJSON` and `toString` methods? Can you provide us more information about the class `BaseSchema` and where you're instantiating the `new Person` and calling the `toJSON | toString`?

Comment: Yes the implementation for both is the same and the code is above. The problem does _not_ require that you ever call the toJSON or toString methods, the compile time error is shown above and prevents transpilation.

Comment: I do realize that I could use the `Partial<T>` modifier to avoid the requirement for `toJSON()` but that would unnecessarily water down the typing requirements for other use cases.

Comment: The main problem is that you are passing an object as an instance of your class. You need to instantiate the class with `name` and `age` (or any other properties needed) and then pass the instance to that set function. The instance will contain the defined methods by default.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the properties to serve as the contract for the interface. This _does_ work. What I'm also wanting is to exclude methods from that interface definition (aka, `toJSON`).

Answer (score 1):

Typescript has a structural type system in which type compatibility is determined by structural compatibility. This means that an object literal with all the fields and methods of the `Person` class is compatible with a parameter of type `Person` .

If our class only has fields and the`toString` method, any object literal with the mandatory fields will be compatible, as the `toString` method exist implicitly on all objects. As soon as you add other methods the compiler starts to complain that the object literal does not have the extra methods. You could make the object literal compatible again by defining the extra methods, but the object literal will still not be an instance of the class

```
class Person{
  name: string;
  toJson() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

let literal: Person = {
  name: '',
  toJson() { return '';}
}
console.log(literal instanceof Person) //false!
```

You should define a constructor that takes the fields of the class as a parameter and assigns them to the fields of the class.  And then use `new` to create instances of the class:

```
type NonMethodKeys<T> = ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : P } & { [x: string]: never })[keyof T];  
type RemoveMethods<T> = Pick<T, NonMethodKeys<T>>; 

class Person {
  constructor(data: RemoveMethods<Person>) {
    Object.assign(this, data)
  }
  name: string;
  toJson() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

let aPerson: Person = new Person({
  name: '',
});

console.log(aPerson instanceof Person) //true
```

Or if you want the set method to just take the fields of person, you could use `RemoveMethods<Person>` as the type parameter to `set` but I'm not sure what `set` does and if it cares that the parameter is an actual instance of`Person` or if it just requires something with the fields of `Person`

```
db.set<RemoveMethods<Person>>('url', {
  name:'',
  age:42
}) // should compile but might not work, hard to say without more info on set
```

Comment: many thanks, well explained. In my case the parameter passed in requires only that the _required attributes_ of the class be passed but nothing else. I think the `<RemoveMethods<Person>>` approach will likely work best for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Actually @Titian it appears those first two type definitions, produce a lot of errors. I was just going through to fully grok them but is it possible there's a typo in them somewhere.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `@property` decorator is actually a way to determine what _should_ be in the interface rather than removing the methods. Not sure if that makes it easier.

Comment: @ken  what error are you getting? I am using Typescript 2.8. if you are on a previous version you don't have conditional types, so you will have to settle for `Partial<Person>`. Sorry for the delay, I feel asleep :-)